# Dynamically add fields to my form when clicking the previous field

Tags: javascript, dynamic, field, addition

So, what I'm trying to do is both add multiple text fields and upload multiple files. The user should only see 1 field for uploading until having clicked it, and it is browsing for the file. Same goes for the text-fields. When a user clicks or starts typing in the text field the next will appear. I have so far had no luck in accomplishing my goal. I'm just starting with JavaScript so my code is badly broken, and not even worth posting.

What are the different ways of doing this and do you know the pros and cons?

Edit: This is one of the many ways I tried to do it.

```
<form name="form">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file[0]" id="file[0]" onclick="addForm()" />
</form>
<br />

<script type="text/javascript">

var part1 = '<label for="file">Filename:</label> <input type="file" name="file[';
var part2 = ']" id="file[';
var part3 =']" onclick="form()" /><br />'

var counter = 0;

function addForm()
{

if (document.form.file[counter].click) 
{
        document.write(part1 + counter + part2 + counter + part3);
        counter++;

}
}
</script>
```

Comment: If you can't be bothered to show your code (we can even work with, and improve, broken code) then why should we bother trying to help? Also, please don't use needless profanity in your questions.

Comment: 1) both your variable and function have the same name. The function will replace the variable. 2) `document.write(var form)` is not valid javascript. It would be `document.write(form)`, but you'll want to either change the function name or the variable name so that they don't match. 3) `document.write` adds the passed text to the end of the document, so it won't be added to your form element. Use `appendChild` 4) I believe all of your labels will point to the first file input. You'd  probably be better off leaving the `for` attribute off the label and nesting the file input inside of it.

Comment: Thank you all =) I feel I should study the basics of JavaScript a bit more, :P Until next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick solution: http://jsfiddle.net/JTDZR/

It will add a new file input when a file is selected for the currently active file input, then it will disable the current file input, so only one is enabled at a time.

HTML

```
<form id="fups" name="form">
<label>
    Filename: <input type="file" name="file[]" />
</label>
</form>​
```

JS

```
var fups = document.getElementById("fups");
var file = document.form['file[]'];

fups.onchange = function(){
    file.disabled = true;
    var inp = document.createElement("input");
    inp.type = "file";
    inp.name = "file[]";
    var lab = document.createElement("label");
    lab.innerHTML = "Filename: ";
    lab.appendChild(inp);

    fups.appendChild(lab);
    file = inp;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have this HTML:

```
<form id="myForm">
   <input type="text" />
   <input type="file" />
   <!-- the JS won't affect this element -->
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

A fairly simplified version of the javascript you might use would look like this:

```
var formElement = document.getElementById("myForm");
var children = e.getElementsByTagName("input");
var allowedTypes = new Array("text", "", "file");
// note the empty string - it stands for the default "text" type
for(var i=0; i<children.length) {
   var input = children[i];
   if(0 > allowedTypes.indexOf(input.attributes.getNamedItem("type").value)) {
      input.onFocus = function() {
         formElement.innerHTML += input.outerHTML;
         input.onFocus = null;
      }
   }
}
```

This could derive in a more complex example, like with added container for the new inputs so they won't always appear at the end of the form. Also, I would consider working with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It is a personal opinion, of course, but it saves me LOTS of time and coding.

Comment: You're welcome. If it answers your question, you can mark it as such :)